# Помогите организовать выборку jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Задача: создать массив с дальнейшим обращением к каждому элементу через цикл.
На странице две таблицы с идентификаторами. В каждой таблице есть ячейки с классом "can".
Массив должен состоять из ячеек с классом "can" первой таблицы.
Пример кода:

```
<table id="tab1">
<tr>
<td class="can"></td>
<td class="can"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="tab2">
<tr>
<td class="can"></td>
<td></td>
<td class="can"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Естественно таблицы гораздо больше, поэтому обращаться к каждой ячейки через id не рационально.

Я попытался сделать так:

```
var tb13 = new Array();
tb13 = $('#tab1>td[class=can]');
```

Но не работает. Есть идеи?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cелектор `>` означает неподсредственно дочерний элемент, т.е. для `table` это `tr`, но не `td`.

Следовательно, в вашем случае всё предельно просто:

```
var tb13 = $('#tab1 .can').get(); 
//или
var tb13 = $('#tab1').find('.can').get();
```

- [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)
- [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)
- [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)
- [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Как же всё оказалось просто)
Спасибо.
Пойду перечитывать документацию.

Comment: документация jQuery как и её исходники - крайне полезное и интересное чтиво

Comment: @mccrush, и не забудьте прочитать про метод [.each()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0), раз вам надо в цикле обращаться к каждому элементу таблицы.

Comment: [gray]*оффтоп*[/gray]

@Spectre, если я не ошибаюсь, поправочка: для `table` дочерний эллемент не `tr`, а `tbody`.

Comment: это уже от верстальщика зависит, в случае ТС`а это `tr`